# how to exit webview after submit in react native

Tags: react-native

If using webview for user login, we want to close the webview automatically after user submit their info. How to achieve that?

I have seen this being done when using Facebook sign in library, when user login with Facebook, it closes the website and calls the callback.

I am using 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'

Answer (score 0):

you can do it use webView interact with js. firstly, when the user clicks the login button to submit their info, the html can post a message use `window.postMessage("content")` ., then in the react-native webview add `onMessage` handle.

```
<WebView
onMessage={this.onMessage}
...
/>

onMessage = (message) => {
  // the message is you posted by window.postMessage

 }
```

for react-native > 0.6; you should change to use `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage`.

Besides that, you can also use the `injectJavaScripts`. for more details about webview interact with js, you can read this [artticle](https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/communicating-between-react-native-and-the-webview-ac14b8b8b91a)